# I am not sure how to write the query below

Tags: sql

I need some assistance in writing a query - for What is the most recent location of the person with the most debt on their credit card. This is my first time using forum and I am new to SQL Any and all help is appreciated

Comment: Show us what you have so far. Without knowing that or your database schema no one here can help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Normally on SO for a question like this, it is typically required that you demonstrate what you currently have in terms of your query, and indicate where you're having trouble, and/or what is the expected behaviour versus the observed behaviour. Otherwise, its difficult to tell whether someone is attempting to have their work done for them, or has a genuine question.

Comment: You should read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31930105/row-count-to-start-over-based-on-order for an example of a well formatted and complete question.

Comment: My table looks like thisTransaction ID | Date | Person ID | Credit | Location

Comment: And i am a bit confused about getting the MOST RECENT date and of the person with the MOST credit because of there are two aggregate functions together

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing we can really do for you unless you show us what you have, in terms of your database. This also isn't a place for getting people to do your work for you.

What you need to do for this problem is a simple SELECT query, and using the max function find the record with the highest credit card debt, and the name of that person.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp

Above is a site where you can look at how to use the MAX function,, and even practice it with some fake data.

This might look like 
:SELECT Name, MAX(CCDEBT) FROM `MyDatabase`

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. I will ask better questions in the future.